# last column name is not bold when applying bold font to column names together with hiding index before converting to latex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

I am trying to convert pandas dataframe to latex with column names in bold font at the sam time , with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(name=['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
         mask=['red', 'purple'],
         weapon=['sai', 'bo staff']
        )
)
print(df.style.hide(axis="index").applymap_index(lambda v: "font-weight: bold;", axis="columns").to_latex(convert_css=True))
```

which results in:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\bfseries name & \bfseries mask & weapon \\
Raphael & red & sai \\
Donatello & purple & bo staff \\
\end{tabular}
```

where the last column name is not in bold font.

If I do not hid index with:

```
print(df.style.applymap_index(lambda v: "font-weight: bold;", axis="columns").to_latex(convert_css=True))
```

the result will be:

```
\begin{tabular}{llll}
 & \bfseries name & \bfseries mask & \bfseries weapon \\
0 & Raphael & red & sai \\
1 & Donatello & purple & bo staff \\
\end{tabular}
```

where the last column name is in bold font.

This seems to be a bug of pandas, and I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52218) .
So any work around before the bug is fixed?